# iphone app to interact with website

Tags: iphone, xml, web-services, json

Please forgive this simplistic iphone development question. I have written a web application in PHP and perl using a MySQL backend. The users log in with a username and password, and then are able to navigate around the site looking at there respective data.

I have decided to begin developing an iPhone app which will interact with the server (Linux Redhat that I have full control over). Now I know this is possible and I'm sure there are many tutorials out there to help so I am not asking for a 'how-to' here. What I would like to know is what should be my approach ie where do I start?? Some questions...

1) Should I be using a web service installed on my server, and if so which one?
2) How should I pass username and password data to the website if not using web service?
3) How easy is it to send the username/password, and receive any data securely ie HTTPS?
4) The old debate of JSON or XML for receiving data +/- sending login details??!

As I said, I am just looking for ideas/pointers on how to approach this project.

Thanks once again,
Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) It's up to you, you can create a RESTful web service and iPhone application which I personally preferred.

for 2),3) [see](http://wiki.tolven.org/doc/index.php/RESTful_User_Authentication)

4) use JSON, it saves your bandwidth.

> Alternatively you can develop a mobile website using somthing like
>   Sencha Touch or jQuery Mobile and convert it into a native application

Comment: thanks dasun, do you have any particular JSON webservices for a RH5 Linux server (running apache 2) in mind that you would recommend? Andy

Comment: It's not depend on the platform or language, you just have to write a normal web service which returns JSON response for your custom HTTP requests. If you are using an OOP language you can simply create a object with the response data you want to send and send the response by serializing the object to a json string.

Answer (score 0):

If you use JSON, dont forget to write some robust validation code to cope with malicious requests. The advantage of using XML is that you can use a validating parser and write a schema for all your documents, which can save you a lot of time and make your application more resilient to malformed requests.

I recommend you use a REST Web service over HTTPS, it makes things so much simpler.